# SSRS - How to lay out query results in style other than generic table

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, layout, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I am creating an SSRS report in Visual Studio 2012. I have a parameter `ID` and the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Email, Title, Address
FROM EmployeeTable
WHERE ID = @ID
```

`ID` is a unique identifier, so this query will only ever return one set of results. With these results I want to populate a report designed like the picture below:
[image]
I know how to easily create a 1-row table with these values, but I can't figure out how to have the values put in the proper places here. I also understand why this wouldn't work with multiple rows worth of values, but it seems like it should be possible with just one set of results. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the table to work the way you want by just Inserting a new table.

Then on the **detail row** (with the 3 lines) right-click and **Add Group** > **Inside Group - Below**.

Then add your second row of details.

[image]